# ClassCastException when retrieving custom view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout like this:

```
<com.mypackage.QuadPaneHorizontalSplit
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- more views here -->

</com.mypackage.QuadPaneHorizontalSplit>
```

The class QuadPaneHorizontalSplit extends QuadPaneLayout (which extends LineraLayout):

```
public class QuadPaneHorizontalSplit extends QuadPaneLayout {

    public QuadPaneHorizontalSplit(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public QuadPaneHorizontalSplit(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public QuadPaneHorizontalSplit(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isVerticalSplit() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

After settings the layout with setContentView I try to retrieve the custom view:

```
QuadPaneLayout quadPaneLayout = (QuadPaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
```

which works great in general but I got some crash reports with the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mypackage.QuadPaneHorizontalSplit
>   cannot be cast to com.mypackage.QuadPaneLayout

QuadPaneHorizontalSplit clearly extends QuadPaneLayout so the exception should not be possible. I get  crash reports from Android 4.x devices and different manufacturers. Interesting is that all the devices are rooted so maybe this is an issue with some custom rom? Note that this line of code is executed thousands of times each day without issues and so far I got only 13 crashes (BugSense) but I'd still like to get to the bottom of this.

I know about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7823787/534471 but I'm not using include for this layout and I wouldn't want to add a merge tag because that might have undesired effects.

Anyone has an idea what's going on here?

Comment: Could you post your QuadPaneHorizontalSplit class completely?

Comment: I posted the complete QuadPaneHorizontalSplit class but it really only consists of constructors and one extra method. The actual code is in QuadPaneLayout but I'm not going to post those >650 lines of code as I don't think they are relevant.

Comment: Could you try  QuadPaneHorizontalSplit quadPaneLayout = (QuadPaneHorizontalSplit) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);

Comment: @nurisezgin That's not the solution because obviously there's a QuadPaneVerticalSplit too and I need their common super class which is QuadPaneLayout.

Comment: Do you have another "QuadPaneLayout" class. (Maybe different package same class name.)

Comment: @nurisezgin no just this one class

Comment: Try casting it in linear layout. Are you getting this error in activity or in any adapter?

Comment: And Proguard is not enabled either, so that is "optimizes" the class in some way, right?

Comment: @Abhishek Dhiman QuadPaneVerticalSplit is a QuadPaneLayout is a LinearLayout so why would casting it to a LinearLayout be different from casting it to its direct super class? Also I need a QuadPaneLayout to call all my custom methods (LinearLayout wouldn't give me access to these methods).

Comment: @beworker ProGuard is used but if ProGuard would remove the super class then it wouldn't work at all. As I mentioned in my question it works thousands of times each day but I do get the occasional crash report. The only common denominator I found so far is that all the crashes happened on rooted devices with at least Android 4.x.

Comment: I would ask users about what runtime they use. This might be new ART runtime issue.

Comment: @beworker that's a good idea. Unfortunately none of them contacted me so I can't ask them. I only have the crash reports. I have three devices running ART without that issue. Because of that and the fact that all devices affected by this issue are rooted lead me to the conclusion that this must something related to a custom rom (but which one...).

Comment: Once you know which device is this, just exclude it from the list of supported devices. Save your time for better stuff ;)

Comment: @beworker: I'm not going to exclude the Samsung Galaxy S3 ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this question which might be of interest to other developers too.

Since I had lots of other inexplicable crashes including VerifyErrors, ClassNotFoundExceptions and ActivityNotFoundExceptions I got suspicious about the origin of these crash reports. I added some "extra code" to make sure the app wasn't tampered with and if it was the bug report would show this. Indeed all the ClassCastException crashes happened in instances of my app that were obviously cracked which would also explain why I got this crash reports only for the paid version of the app and why the paid app seems to crash much more often than the free one.

Maybe it's time to spend that extra money for a DexGuard license...

Comment: Can you provide a reference source?

Comment: What do you mean with reference source?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... This happens to me sometimes, but this is usually fixed once I clean the project. In this case, this seems to be os/device/user specific. How often are you casting from QuadPaneHorizontalSplit to QuadPaneLayout? Do you perhaps have another instance of "R.id.root_layout" where it is not the same View Object? Maybe this is causing the issue?

**Edit**: Nevermind, I forgot the ClassCastException is specifically from QuadPaneHorizontalSplit to QuadPaneLayout, so it is probably not another instance of "R.id.root_layout". What other information are you getting from BugSense?

Comment: If you read the question carefully you would see that the exception is not usually thrown (it's not reproducible) so it's not about rebuilding the project and such.
I get all kinds of information like memory, os version, screen resolution, mobile network / wlan, language, country you name it